# How to Update multiple rows having specific count with Group by clause?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, duplicates

I want to update multiple rows that have specific count number (count(*)=2) with number 40. Consider the following example:

```
create table test(id int not null primary key, day date not null, tst int not null  );
insert into test(id, day, tst) values(1, '2006-10-08', 0);

insert into test(id, day, tst) values(2, '2006-10-08', 0);

insert into test(id, day,tst) values(3, '2006-10-09', 0);
```

I have used the following query `UPDATE test SET tst = 40 WHERE (select day from test GROUP BY day having count(*)=2);`

But it never works. Any help please...

Thanks.

Aymen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks God... Finally, we came up with working query:

```
UPDATE test1 SET tst = 40 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT day FROM (SELECT day from test1 ) 
AS tmpb WHERE test1.day = tmpb.day GROUP BY day HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example (used Oracle instead of mysql, but syntax should be similar, if not identical):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (tst int, DAY INT)

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (4, 5);

UPDATE TEST
   SET tst = 40
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DAY FROM TEST t2 WHERE t2.day = test.day GROUP BY DAY HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
SELECT * FROM TEST;


Result:
    TST DAY
1   40  4
2   40  4
3   4   5
```

Comment: Thanks dcp, it doesn't work for me! I am using Mysql 5.1.33. Is the UPDATE sentence ends with "HAVING COUNT(*) = 2);" I think the second sentence of "select * from test" is just for showing up the results. Isn't it? any way, I've used the sentence as it above and with separation the SELECT clause but never works. On separation case, I got this message "You can't specify target table 'test1' for update in FROM clause".

Comment: I used test1 table instead of test.

Comment: I came up with this query which is also not working! But I think it is closer to the correct one. Isn't it?!
UPDATE test1 SET tst = 40 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT day FROM (SELECT day from test1 t2) AS tmpb  WHERE  test1.day = t2.day   GROUP BY day HAVING COUNT(*) = 2);  the error here is " Unknown column 't2.day' in 'where clause'"